# 2D array summation operations

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to figure out a way to solve my research problem. I have a 2D array, or so-called nested list with dimension let's say 3*30;

```
list = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.994429, 0.980929, 0.971825, 
0.967241, 0.967241, 0.971825, 0.980929, 0.994429, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.998888, 0.971825, 
0.948683, 0.929755, 0.915302, 0.905539, 0.900617, 0.900617, 
0.905539, 0.915302, 0.929755, 0.948683, 0.971825, 0.998888, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.971825, 0.939267, 0.910433,
0.885689, 0.865384, 0.849837, 0.839312, 0.834, 0.834, 0.839312, 
0.849837, 0.865384, 0.885689, 0.910433, 0.939267, 0.971825, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

So each row will have 30 elements and there are 3 rows totally.

The `TableForm` is clearly showing them:

[image]

Imagine this list has ten 3*3 element blocks. For example,the first and second block both has 9 zeros.
I want to calculate the total value of each block and generate a new list in which every element is the summation for that small block. So it will generate 1*10 list in the end.

**What I have done so far:**

I think first I could partition the original list into some small groups.

```
list = Partition[Flatten[list], 3]
```

And then using `Part` to subtract the small groups and do further operations.
Maybe something like 
     `list[[1]]+list[[11]]+list[[21]]`
could gives me similar results. But I am confused if I am doing this too clumsy. Could you give some of your thoughts? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
BlockMap[Total[#, 2]&, list, {3, 3}]
```

> {{0, 0, 2.90998, 6.5062, 8.1646, 8.1646, 6.5062, 2.90998, 0, 0}}

Also:

```
Partition[list, {3, 3}, {3, 3}, None, {}, Plus]
```

> {{0, 0, 2.90998, 6.5062, 8.1646, 8.1646, 6.5062, 2.90998, 0, 0}}

Comment: The first one is also very handy! Thanks for the sharing!

Comment: @cj9435042, Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a nested partition and sum at the two deepest levels

```
Total[Partition[list, {3, 3}], {3, 4}]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 2.90998, 6.506198, 8.164602, 8.164602, 6.506198, 2.90998, 0, 0}}
> ```

Or more general:

```
block = {3, 3};
Total[Partition[list, block], {Length[block] + 1, ∞}]
```

Comment: Actually,I like this one the most because it is very easy to understand. But I find that this may not apply to other dimensions , for example, for 5 * 5 blocks. Anyway a big thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Because I wanted to use [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html)(although it seems to be an overkill here):

```
array = Transpose /@ ArrayReshape[Transpose@list, {10, 3, 3}];
MatrixForm /@ array
```

[image]

```
Total /@ Flatten /@ array
```

> {0, 0, 2.90998, 6.5062, 8.1646, 8.1646, 6.5062, 2.90998, 0, 0}

---

The `Transpose /@` in `array` is not needed, I used it to obtain a clear display. In short:

```
Total /@ Flatten /@ ArrayReshape[Transpose@list, {10, 3, 3}]
```

gives the desired output.

Comment: [`TakeList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeList.html) could be also used, but I don't have v11.2.